# Python : How can two GTK widgets interact with each other?

Tags: python, gtk

What is the proper way to interact with a button without actually clicking on it?

I have a button "button", that can, upon click :

- Call the method "the_method" that will print what argument (here "filename") has been passed to it
- toggle its own attributes, here its icon.

And I have a treeview, whose rows must, upon double click :

- Call the method "the_method" that will print what argument (here "filename") has been passed to it
- toggle "button"'s attributes, here its icon.

And only the 1st part works. The "foo" function is called (via a callback for the button, directly for the treeview item) and the argument ("filename") is retrieved OK, but how to execute part 2 of the job (changing "button"'s attributes, here its icon)?

---

```
import gtk

class Lister(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hbox = gtk.HBox()

        liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(["foo"])
        liststore.append(["bar"])
        treeview = gtk.TreeView(liststore)
        self.hbox.pack_start(treeview, False)
        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column 1")
        col.pack_start(cell, True)
        col.set_attributes(cell,text=0)
        treeview.connect('row-activated', self.open_file)
        treeview.append_column(col)

    def open_file(self, button, *args):
        Buttons().the_method(self, "foo")

class Buttons(object):

    OPEN_IMAGE = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ADD, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
    CLOSED_IMAGE = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_REFRESH, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)

    def __init__(self):

        self.button = gtk.Button() # THIS is the button to modify
        self.hbox = gtk.HBox()
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.button, False)
        self.button.set_image(self.OPEN_IMAGE)

        self.button.connect('clicked', self.the_method, "plop")
        self.toggled = True

    def the_method(self, button, filename):
        print filename
        print vars(self)

        if self.toggled:
            self.button.set_image(self.CLOSED_IMAGE)
            self.toggled = False
        else:
            self.button.set_image(self.OPEN_IMAGE)
            self.toggled = True

class GUI(object):

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_size_request(100, 150)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start(Buttons().hbox, False, False, 1)
        vbox.pack_start(Lister().hbox)

        self.window.add(vbox)
        self.window.show_all()
        return

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI()
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i don't know anything about python but i have some experiences with `gtk+` and i'm more or less familiar with its concepts.

The first thing i noticed is that you define a class called `GUI` and two separate classes called `Buttons` and `Lister`. For me such approach makes only sense if you design the two last mentioned classes in a way that they are a kind of (composite) widget theirselves. So that you can instantiate them at a higher level for example in the GUI class. This would be a generic approach and makes perfectly sense if you want to reuse these new widgets.

The way you did it doesn't make sense to me. From what i have gathered so far the actual aim of `Buttons` and `Lister` is to populate your main application window with widgets, to connect callbacks to signals of those widgets and to define these callbacks as methods.

I think you limit the flexibility of gtk if you make it this way. For example you connect signals to callbacks at a point where in principle you aren't able to access all the widgets of your interface. In contrast, I prefer a common place in the code at which i connect signals to callbacks and at which i can principally pass all widgets of interest to a specific callback.

In fact one often have to act upon several widgets from inside a callback. So you have to consider to implement the callbacks as methods of your GUI class where they can principally access all elements of your user interface.

Also you should consider to design your interface with `glade`. That way your code would be much more legible.

---

Supplement (after some code pushing):

```
import gtk

class GUI(object):

    OPEN_IMAGE = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ADD, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
    CLOSED_IMAGE = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_REFRESH, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
    toggled = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_size_request(100, 150)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", gtk.main_quit)

        vbox = gtk.VBox()

        self.button = gtk.Button() # THIS is the button to modify
        self.button.set_image(self.OPEN_IMAGE)

        liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(["foo"])
        liststore.append(["bar"])
        self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(liststore)
        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column 1")
        col.pack_start(cell, True)
        col.set_attributes(cell,text=0)
        self.treeview.append_column(col)

        vbox.pack_start(self.button, False, False, 1)
        vbox.pack_start(self.treeview, False, False, 1)

        self.treeview.connect('row-activated', self.the_method_wrapper, "plop")
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.the_method, "plop")

        self.window.add(vbox)
        self.window.show_all()
        return

    def the_method_wrapper(self, button, *args):
        self.the_method(self, "foo")

    def the_method(self, button, filename):
        print filename
        print vars(self)

        if self.toggled:
            self.button.set_image(self.CLOSED_IMAGE)
            self.toggled = False
        else:
            self.button.set_image(self.OPEN_IMAGE)
            self.toggled = True


def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI()
    main()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not very helpful. What you advice in the 1st paragraph is basically what I'm doing (or did during the many hours of trial and error). I did this skeleton working code to try and get concrete, working  answers to the question "how can my lister access my button", not vague "you should consider glade".
I don't want to sound ungrateful, but your answer should really be a comment. And now I'm alone again. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Oh and BTW, I tried putting everything in the same class as you advised, that was days ago. The problem was exatly the same, and lies in my inability to understand how widgets interact together, hence the title of my question. why do you say "In fact you often have to act upon several widgets from inside a callback"? That's cold : This is *exactly* what I'm trying to do!

Comment: You definitely need to learn the concepts of `gtk+` before trying to implement a specific project in whichever language. Further it seems to me that you not even attempted to understand my answer. For example your notion of widgets equals that of a simple class. But it is not as simple. Widgets got properties, signals, methods and maybe implement one or more interfaces. All of that is based on glib's GObject system and it is helpful to see them as abstract as they could be. And the question of the interaction of widgets is about the scope of those instances and the glue code you have to write.

Comment: Thank you very much ; this is *exactly* what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly disagree with user1146332 answer. This is not a GTK+ issue, nor a strong design issue, just an object oriented programming issue. The cause of your bug is that you call `the_method` like this:

```
Buttons().the_method(self, "foo")
```

This can't work, because you're mixing up two different fundamental things: a class, and an instance of a class. When you call `Buttons()`, you're creating a new instance of the `Buttons` class. Thus, as this class is not a singleton, you're in fact creating a new instance, with a new GtkButton, and end up not interacting with the button you previously created.

The solution here is to make the `Lister` object aware of what it needs to modify, which means storing around the `Buttons` instance you previously created, for example in `self.button`, and calling `the_method` on it.

```
self.button.the_method("foo")
```

Here's a slightly modified version of your code. The important thing is that the `Lister` instance is now aware of the `Buttons` instance it needs to modify.

```
import gtk

class Lister(object):

    def __init__(self, button):
        self.hbox = gtk.HBox()
        self.button = button

        liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        liststore.append(["foo"])
        liststore.append(["bar"])
        treeview = gtk.TreeView(liststore)
        self.hbox.pack_start(treeview, False)
        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column 1")
        col.pack_start(cell, True)
        col.set_attributes(cell,text=0)
        treeview.connect('row-activated', self.open_file)
        treeview.append_column(col)

    def open_file(self, button, *args):
        self.button.the_method("foo")

class Buttons(object):

    OPEN_IMAGE = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ADD, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
    CLOSED_IMAGE = gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_REFRESH, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)

    def __init__(self):

        self.button = gtk.Button() # THIS is the button to modify
        self.hbox = gtk.HBox()
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.button, False)
        self.button.set_image(self.OPEN_IMAGE)

        self.button.connect('clicked', self.the_method, "plop")
        self.toggled = True

    def the_method(self, filename):
        print filename
        print vars(self)

        if self.toggled:
            self.button.set_image(self.CLOSED_IMAGE)
            self.toggled = False
        else:
            self.button.set_image(self.OPEN_IMAGE)
            self.toggled = True

class GUI(object):

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_size_request(100, 150)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        buttons = Buttons()
        vbox.pack_start(buttons.hbox, False, False, 1)
        vbox.pack_start(Lister(buttons).hbox)

        self.window.add(vbox)
        self.window.show_all()
        return

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI()
    main()
```

However, there's still lots of room for improvement. I suggest you don't use the `__init__` function to create your widgets, but a `create` method that will return the toplevel widget of your widget tree. This is because you can't return anything in `__init__`, so it's easier to use a different method instead of raising exceptions there.

```
b = Buttons()
vbox.pack_start(b.create(), False, False, 1)
l = Lister(b)
vbox.pack_start(l.create(), False, False, 1)
```

Other improvement might be (sorry, i'm using the C naming here for GTK classes/functions, which I know better than the python one):

- using a `GtkToggleButton` instead of tracking the button state yourself
- using gtk_button_set_use_stock to tell the button to interpret the label you will set in the button as the stock id for the button (this may print the associated text too, not sure about this)
- switching to GTK 3 (uses pyGObject), as this is GTK 2 code (uses pyGTK), unless you want Windows compatibility

See you on linuxfr :-)

Comment: Those are really sound advices, specially the widget create method strategy, and +1 for pointing the http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktogglebutton.html, thank you very muche ! ;) J'abuse, but what would you say about that one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160479/python-get-gtk-treeview-selection-from-another-widget ?

Comment: @libreforce: From my point of view your answer is all about improving the initial design descision of the question's author. By the way from which statement do you derive that i blame gtk for whatever. I just said that one limits the flexibility of gtk if one limits the scope of instantiated widgets.

Comment: Sorry if my answer sounded harsh. It's just that one is not forced to change his way of programming with objects just because he's using GTK. And what he's doing was doable without rewriting the whole thing. It has some cons, but both approaches have some.