# Python : Get gtk.treeview selection from another widget

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

It looks like the only way to get the selected item of a `gtk.TreeView()` is to actually click on it :

```
    tree_selection = self.treeview.get_selection()
    tree_selection.connect('changed', self.my_callback)
    self.treeview.connect('row-activated', self.my_other_callback)
```

But what if I'm listing files in my treeview, and need a "file properties"  menu item?
Or a play button, that needs to access selected file to pass the filename to a player class / method ?

Bonus question : How to call `my_other_callback` from `tree_selection.connect('changed', ...)` (that does not seem to return all the row data..?) or in other words, how to pass `treeview` and `path` to the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selection of a tree view, call [the `get_selected_rows` method](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeselection.html#method-gtktreeselection--get-selected-rows) of the `gtk.TreeSelection` object. You can call it at any place from which you can access the tree view.

It is unclear why you want to pass the tree view to `my_other_callback` since it, being a method on your class, can access it as `self.treeview`. But if you want to do it anyway, you can add the tree view (or any other Python object) as an additional argument to `connect`:

```
tree_selection.connect('changed', self.my_other_callback, self.treeview)
```

For an even finer-grained control of how the callback is invoked, use a lambda:

```
tree_selection.connect('changed', lambda *args: self.my_other_callback(self.treeview))
```

This allows you to use the same handler for multiple signals without having to declare the handler as accepting `*args`.